# Ruby - group_by month for current year, including months with no data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to write a method to return a very specific data structure for a chart that I am populating.

A user can enter dates for miles that they've hiked, so on the Mile model I have start_date and end_date attributes.

The method I have currently is *close*, however it should return a 0 for the current month because the user hasn't entered any miles hiked for the month of May. I also need to constrain it to the current year, which it currently is not.

Here is what my current method looks like:

```
def miles_by_month
    miles = self.miles.from_this_year.group_by { |t| t.start_date.strftime('%b') }
    total_miles = miles.map do |m|
        { 'indicator': m[0], 'total': m[1].sum(&:length) }
    end
    total_miles
end
```

And the 'from_this_year' scope on the Mile model if it's helpful:

```
scope :from_this_year, lambda { where("start_date > ? AND start_date < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_year, Time.now.end_of_year) }
```

And here is an example of what it returns:

```
[
    [0] {
        :indicator => "Jan",
            :total => 15
    },
    [1] {
        :indicator => "Feb",
            :total => 10
    },
    [2] {
        :indicator => "Mar",
            :total => 10
    },
    [3] {
        :indicator => "Apr",
            :total => 100
    },
    [4] {
        :indicator => "May",    # I need [4] to show up with 
        :total => 0             # a total of 0. [4] currently
    }                           # does not show up at all.
]
```

"Indicator" refers to the name of the month, and "total" refers to a sum of the number of miles that user has hiked for that specific month.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**

I have modified my `miles_by_month` method somewhat based on an answer here to the following:

```
def miles_by_month
    months = Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[1..12]
    miles = self.miles.from_this_year.group_by { |t| t.start_date.strftime('%b') }

    total_miles = miles.map do |m|
        { 'indicator': m[0], 'total': m[1].sum(&:length) }
    end

    months.each do |month|
      unless total_miles.any? { |r| r[:indicator] == month }
        total_miles.push(indicator: month, total: 0)
      end
    end

    total_miles
  end
```

The only remaining thing I need to do is figure out how to constrain the months variable from the start of the year to the current month.

Comment: What does it return now? Are you seeing an error? What if the `Mile` model was named `Hike` instead, would that be more or less clear?

Comment: It more or less returns "correctly", in that it's grouping by month and giving me a total by month. There are no errors. I'll update my original post with an example of what it's returning. With regards to constraining it to the current year, I've added a scope to the Mile model that appears to be working called `from_this_year`, so I'll update the method in the original post as well to include that scope.

Comment: Now all that remains is my need to return a :total of 0 if there was no data entered for that month. For example, this month a user has not entered any miles, so it should return { :indicator => "May", :total => 0 } in addition to the other data

Comment: What does it return when no data has been entered for May?

Comment: Nothing, because it doesn't exist. I'll need to essentially force May (or whatever month doesn't have any data) to return 0 within the method.

Comment: When should it stop? Should it only take into account which month today is in? Or should it list zeroes for every month until the end of the calendar year? Or farther?

Comment: I should've clarified that. It should go all the way up to the current month. So if I haven't entered data for January and May, it should return a 0 for both of those months and the total miles for February, March and April.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Max Pleaner's answer, I was able to come up with the following method to correctly return what I needed:

```
def miles_by_month
    cur_month = Time.now.month
    months = Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[1..cur_month]
    miles = self.miles.from_this_year.group_by { |t| t.start_date.strftime('%b') }

    total_miles = miles.map do |m|
        { 'indicator': m[0], 'total': m[1].sum(&:length) }
    end

    months.each do |month|
      unless total_miles.any? { |r| r[:indicator] == month }
        total_miles.push(indicator: month, total: 0)
      end
    end

    total_miles
  end
```

This returns a data structure like the following:

```
[
    [0] {
        :indicator => "Jan",
            :total => 15
    },
    [1] {
        :indicator => "Feb",
            :total => 10
    },
    [2] {
        :indicator => "Mar",
            :total => 10
    },
    [3] {
        :indicator => "Apr",
            :total => 100
    },
    [4] {
        :indicator => "May",
            :total => 0
    }
]
```

It's certainly not the most efficient method and I'd be very curious to see if anyone has more efficient ways of handling this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by looping over each of the months and setting a default value, for example:

```
MONTHS = Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[1..12]

# put this somewhere
MONTHS.each do |month|
  unless results.any? { |r| r[:indicator] == month }
    results.push(indicator: month, total: 0)
  end
end

# you can sort them chronologically if needed
results.sort_by! { |r| MONTHS.index(r[:indicator]) }
```

Note this is not *the most* efficient code - it has some O(N^2) stuff which can be optimized to O(N) - but it should hopefully give you a starting point

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to get this to work with my existing code. Setting `MONTHS` to that Date object makes sense (didn't even know ABBR_MONTHNAMES was a thing!), but after that it gets fuzzy. In your code above, what does `results` refer to?

Comment: @J.Jackson You said "And here is an example of what it returns:" I am assuming we refer to that with a "results" variable, e.g. an array of hashes

Comment: Ah so I would essentially run my existing method, then run it through the method you've posted above (with results being equal to my example return above)?

Comment: @J.Jackson yeah

Comment: I was able to combine the two methods into one, if you'll check the Update in the original post. The only remaining thing to do is to somehow constrain the months variable to months from the beginning of the year to the current month.

Comment: @J.Jackson in the `months.each do |month|`, you can do `break if month == Date.today.strftime "%b"`